# Best Redis Data Type For Distributed Computation

Tags: redis

I have an application that needs to use Redis with the following requirements:

- A producer storing tens of millions of string records up to 128 bytes each
- Indexing the records as each worker needs to access records from its own determined range `X` to `Y` in order for multiple workers to be able to process in parallel
- Deleting the processed records and storing the results back in redis under a different index

Which redis data type is optimal for this?

I am considering ordered sets, where I would write original strings in one set and results in another, though I have read somewhere that they come with a 64 byte overhead and I'd like to save on memory as much as possible as that allows me to process more records. Another alternative is a simple `SET key value` where I would index let's say `0-100,000,000` as records to be processed and `100,000,000-200,000,000` as the corresponding result records.

Does anyone know how much memory overhead exists for each solution or can even propose a better one?

Comment: Did you consider using the RediSearch module?

Comment: @GuyKorland No as I'm trying to minimize storage overhead and there's really no need for secondary indexing, more complex queries and the like